# Obtaining "Load key "/root/.ssh/": Is a directory When Executing "ssh -i ~/.ssh root@IP_address

Tags: ssh

I am attempting to log into an instance I created in the IBM cloud.

When I attempt to execute the command "ssh -i ~/.ssh root@[IP_address of my instance], I receive the error "Load key "/root/.ssh/": Is a directory
root@[IP_address of my instance]'s password:

Prior to executing this command, I did run ssh-keygen and was able to generate  new set of files i.e., id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.

I have run the chmod 700 on the 2 files id_rsa and id_rsa.pub but this appears to not have worked.

Can someone help me understand why the command above i.e., "ssh -i ~/.ssh root@[IP_address of my instance] results in this error?

Answer (score 1):

The `-i` option requires the name of the private key *file*, not the name of the directory *containing* the file:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@[IP_address of my instance]
```

However, since `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the default RSA key file, you can omit the `-i` option and its argument altogether

```
ssh root@[IP_address of my instance]
```

Of course, for the authentication to succeed you will need to have copied the public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote account - using `ssh-copy-id` or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Very much appreciated!